# Rename reference to Django messages in templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django's messaging framework to alert a user that a message was sent successfully. By default, you display a Django message in a template using {{ messages }}. I want to avoid any possibility of confusion by renaming the variable to refer to Django's system message as something like {{ system_message }}, leaving {{ message }} free for referring to user messages.

I've tried doing something like

```
from django.contrib import messages as system_message
```

but renaming it in this context doesn't carry through to my template. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages isn't a template tag but a template context variable provided by the `"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"` processor. I think the best way to rename it is simply replacing django's context processor with your own version, e.g:

```
from django.contrib.messages.api import get_messages

def messages(request):
    """
    Returns a lazy 'messages' context variable.
    """
    return {'your_name_space': get_messages(request)}
```